# How to read characters from the right until a slash is reached

Tags: string, excel, search, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a column ("E") containing numbers in this format:

```
879/13
879/2
879/6
```

I want to split the numbers into two columns. I solved the left side, but the right side is giving me troubles, more specifically numbers with only a single digit after the slash, as they return /Number. How do I fix this?

My formulas:

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(E2;SEARCH("/";E2)-1));E2;LEFT(E2;SEARCH("/";E2)-1))

=IF(ISERROR(RIGHT(E2;SEARCH("/";E2)-1));E2;RIGHT(E2;SEARCH("/";E2)-2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems Text to Columns with `/` as delimiter might be more suitable but you might try:

```
=IFERROR(MID(E2;FIND("/";E2)+1;LEN(E2));"")
```

Comment: This works. For completeness' sake: `=IF(ISERROR(MID(E2;FIND("/";E2)+1;LEN(E2)));"";(MID(E2;FIND("/";E2)+1;LEN(E2))))`

Comment: Haha yes. I didn't notice the edit before I sent my comment. Either works, yours is a bit more elegant, though.

Answer (score 0):

- you can use the excel's inbuilt functionality of "Text to columns" from "Data tab".

[image]

- now select the range which you want to convert and than click on text to columns.

[image]

- now Choose **"Delimited"** option and click next

[image]

- Now keep tick mark on only **Other** and in the box write **"/"** as shown in pic

[image]

- Now click on **"Finish"** and Voilaa it's done !!!!!

[image]

Comment: This works too ofc but I needed a dynamic solution, that's why I used a formula.

Comment: I have added another answer for making data more dynamic by using macro

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your data is in first column and starting with "A1' cell as well as there is no blank cell in between data.

```
Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=True, OtherChar _
    :="/", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```